# Does $\lim\inf n^2$ equal $\infty$ or does not exist?

Tags: calculus, limsup-and-liminf

Does  $\lim\inf n^2$ equal $\infty$ or does not exist?

It seems the textbook doesn't specifically talk about this kind of case.

Comment: $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ always exists. Since the sequence $\{n^2\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ doesn't have a convergent subsequence, we conclude that $\liminf n^2 = \infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It equals infinity, $\liminf $ of a sequence always exists.

It's either a real number or $\infty$/$-\infty$.

In this case the sequence converges to infinity so
$$\limsup=\liminf=\lim=\infty!$$